# In Zend, is there a better way to check if a user hasIdentity()?

Tags: zend-framework

Currently, I am using `Zend_Auth::getInstance()->hasIdentity()` to check if my user is logged in in every controller that requires a login. I feel like I am practicing Zend horribly, so I wanted to ask the more experienced and know if this is the proper way to do this? If not, could you please tell me what is?

Answer (score 1):

We use a [Controller plugin](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.plugins.html) (bootstrapped in application.ini config file) that handles our authentications. It checks the requested controller/action in the preDispatch() phase and matches against ACL objects (could be fetched out of DB, config files, XML, etc.). If the user does not have the privilege to access the target controller/action, the a message is stored in the session and user is redirected to another page, displaying the access forbidden message.

If the user needs to have authentication to access the target controller/action, user is redirected to the login action by modifying the request object.

Using this plugin there is no need to check for user authentication/ACL in each controller and so all the "Access" code would be enclosed in one file, the "Access Plugin".

In order to check for user identity we mostly use the same method of "Zend_Auth::getInstance()->hasIdenity()", but this just shows if the user is authenticated or not. the '''getIdentity()''' method of Zend_Auth returns the current user identity, but again just the identity and not more. However if you would need more information of the user, you could store the user information in a session.

We implement our users as data models, so each user is defined as an object. after a user is authenticated on the login action, we create the appropriate user object and store it in the user session, like this:

```
// This could be a sample code in AuthController/processloginAction()
// suppose $username is validated before and stores the username
$user = new Default_Model_User($username);
// now $user is our user object, suppose $log is a Zend_Log instance
$log->info("user id '{$user->getId()}' username: '{$user->getUsername()}' logged in");
$sess = Zend_Session_Namespace('auth');
$sess->user = $user;
```

From now one, the $user property of the session namespace of 'auth' is the user object with all the information you would need about, not just the identity. and whenever you wanted to check if user is logged in (beside using Zend_Auth) you could check for availability of this value on the user session:

```
$sess = Zend_Session_Namespace('auth');
if (!isset($sess->user) || !$sess->user) {
    // user is not logged in, redirect to login page
}
$user = $sess->user;
/*@var $user Default_Model_User*/
$email = $user->getEmail();
```

now we checked for authentication, and have access to user information (email, phone, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

I use a method similar to the method described by Herman Radtke in his blog at http://www.hermanradtke.com/blog/more-reliable-authentication-in-zend-framework/.  Basically create a controller plugin as farzad mentioned:

```
class My_Authentication extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{

    private $_whitelist;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_whitelist = array(
            'index/login'
        );
    }

    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        $controller = strtolower($request->getControllerName());
        $action = strtolower($request->getActionName());
        $route = $controller . '/' . $action;

        if (in_array($route, $this->_whitelist)) {
            return;
        }

        $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
        if ($auth->hasIdentity()) {
            return;
        }

        self::setDispatched(false);
        // handle unauthorized request...
    }
}
```

and then register that plugin in your bootstrap:

```
public function run() {
  $front->registerPlugin(new My_Authentication());
}
```

I generally take this approach a little farther and integrate the Zend_Acl into the system as well.  To do that I would define the plugin below:

class My_Acl_Authentication extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
    {

```
    private $_acl;

    public function __construct($acl)
    {
        $this->_acl = $acl
    }

    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        $controller = strtolower($request->getControllerName());
        $action = strtolower($request->getActionName());
        $route = $controller . '/' . $action;

        if (in_array($route, $this->_whitelist)) {
            return;
        }

        $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
        $role = 'anonymous';
        if ($auth->hasIdentity()) {
            $role = $auth->getStorage->read()->role;
        }

        if ($this->_acl->isAllowed($role, $route)) {
            return;
        }

        self::setDispatched(false);
        // handle unauthorized request...
    }
}
```

If you go this route there is some more work to be done, specifically you have to setup the ACL and then you also have to store the user's role in the auth storage.

Answer (score 0):

Thats perfectly ok to do so but to save you from repeating that code you can extend all your controllers from a class A which is subclass of Zend_Controller_Action . Then inside this class declare a method

```
    protected function hasIdentity()
    {
      return Zend_Auth::getInstance()->hasIdentity();
    }
```

Now in your controller which is subclass of A you can simply do `$this->hasIdentity();` instead